# What type of column in MySQL has to be for this format data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to insert a date like `2017-05-16-00.00.05.190000` in `MySQL`.
What type of column in `MySQL` has to be for this format?
I need logical type (`date`) not `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the allowed date and time types.

```
DATE        '0000-00-00'
TIME        '00:00:00'
DATETIME    '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
TIMESTAMP   '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
YEAR        '0000'
```

There is no way to insert your format. Sorry but you need to use VARCHAR